# Ajax post request - .empty() function not working for some reason

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, request

I have a potential bug, My search bar does a post request via ajax. But on first request, It clears the dom and appends the result but on consequent requests, it wont clear the dom. Please help ?

```
$("#search_button").click(function() {
    const search = $("#search_input").val();
    console.log("*******_____________ search __________", search);
    //sends a post request to route /search in endpoint.js
    $.post("/en/search",
      {
        search
      },
      function(data, status) {
        //emptying the body and appending the new result
        $(".featured_listings_title").empty();
        $(".featured_listings_title").append(`<h4>Search results </h4>`);
        for (item of data) {
          $(".featured").append(searchTemplate(item));
        }
        $(".main_feed").empty();
      });
  });
```

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: `.empty()` followed by `.append()` is the same as `.html()`. Does that work?

Comment: You're not emptying `.featured`, so that loop will append to whatever is already there.

Comment: Without any html, a guess based on the description would be that on the first request it *overwrites* / removes one of the classes that's used on subsequent requests

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to do. But you should empty before you append. also they need to be in the loop so everytime loop runs, it clears the dom otherwise it will only clear the dom once.
try this:-

```
$("#search_button").click(function() {
    const search = $("#search_input").val();
    console.log("*******_____________ search __________", search);
    //sends a post request to route /search in endpoint.js
    $.post("/en/search",
      {
        search
      },
      function(data, status) {
        
            for (item of data) {
//emptying the body and appending the new result
            $(".featured_listings_title").empty();
            $(".main_feed").empty();
            $(".featured_listings_title").append(`<h4>Search results </h4>`);
              $(".featured").append(searchTemplate(item));
            }
          });
      });
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. emptying the list for every entry would leave only one result in the list.